# Get a determined value inside a dropdowList

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I'm doing a page to edit a product,the product have some characteristics,i'm using a getAll to recover all of the characteristics.

```
model.Listcharacteristics= v_ProdutoCharacteristicsMetodos.GetAll(EmpresaId)
                .Select(x => new ProdutoCharacteristicsModel()
                {
                    Apagado = x.Apagado,
                    DeAte = x.DeAte,
                    DepartamentoId = x.DepartamentoId,
                    Descricao = x.Descricao,
                    Description = x.Description,
                    Fator = x.Fator,
                    Keywords = x.Keywords,
                    MostrarHome = x.MostrarHome,
                    NCM = x.NCM,
                    Ordem = x.Ordem,
                    PessoaId = x.PessoaId,
                    ProdutoFamiliaId = x.ProdutoFamiliaId,
                    UrlImagem = x.UrlImagem
                })
                .ToList();
```

But i have a method that can get the product characteristic by the product ID,so in the edit page,i need to show the currently characteristic instead of the default value,how i can select which value show first select in the dropDowList?

In the BLL i created this.

```
model.Produto.ProdutoFamilia = v_ProdutoFamiliaMetodos.GetById(produtoempresa.ProdutoFamiliaId).Descricao;
```

I'm passing produtoempresa (The product)and ProdutoFamiliaId is the caractheristic ID,i'm getting a string with the name of the characteristic,this name its what i have to show the default value.

The html is this.

```
 <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @if (this.Model.ListFamilia != null && (this.Model.ListFamilia.Count > 0))
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListFamilia.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListFamilia[i].ProdutoFamiliaId)
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListFamilia[i].Descricao)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Produto.ProdutoFamiliaId)*
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Produto.ProdutoFamiliaId, new SelectList(Model.ListFamilia, "ProdutoFamiliaId", "Descricao", Model.Produto.ProdutoFamiliaId), String.Empty)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

In the dropdowList the default value showing must be the model.Produto.ProdutoFamilia.

Comment: If you give us some more information about the framework(s) you are using, the answers can be more specific. For example: is this ASP.NET MVC or WebForms?

Comment: Its a mvc application

Comment: Are you using an HTML helper? HTML.DropdownList[For]?

Comment: No i'm not using,i will post the html i'm using for this

Answer (score 0):

You usually render the dropdown box and set the selected value in the html.  This is done with the

```
<select name="hall" id="hall" value="3">
<option  selected="selected">1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

This will have the first option selected in your dropdown list.  From your method that can get the product characteristic you should be able to calculate which option you want to append

```
selected="selected"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I dont understand how to use this.I'm getting a list of various values based on the EmpresaId (companyId),each is different,so i dont know the fixed value for the dropDowList.Inside this get all,there is the value i received in the variable model.Produto.ProdutoFamilia,i need to check this value and see if this values exist in the getAll list,if yes select him.